# Why can't I upload large files on my PHP website?

Tags: php, apache, file, upload, limit

I am having a problem with uploading files bigger than a certain size (around 150MB/200MB) to my server.
Because I do not have this problem on my local server, I suspect it has something to do with settings on the shared server which I rent that runs Apache.
The error that I am getting is HTML error *413 Request Entity Too Large*

Ofcourse I have done some research and found that the php settings on the server are set correctly as follows:

- *max_input_time = 24000*
- *max_execution_time = 24000*
- *upload_max_filesize = 2048M*
- *post_max_size = 2048M*
- *memory_limit = 4096M*
- *max_input_vars = 2000*

Furthermore, because the server runs on Apache, I made sure to also add
*LimitRequestBody 2147483647* and
*SSLRenegBufferSize 2147483647* to the .htaccess file which translate to 2GB for both settings.

For the code I just use the PHP *move_uploaded_file($_FILES["video"]["tmp_name"], "../videos/". $newVideoName))* method which, one again, does work with smaller files.

Is anyone familiar with this problem or have any other solutions on how to fix this problem? I did talk the my host and they have said that there aren't any restriction on uploaded filesizes other than the PHP settings which I have changed.

Thanks upfront!

Comment: Contact your provider, many of them limit this sort of thing on their end.